# HTML form responsiveness

Tags: jquery, html, forms, responsive-design

I was wondering what's the technology or idea behind the animations that Google Uses on their forms. I want to use it on my personal project.

https://events.google.com/io2015/apply

The radio buttons, Checkboxes and specially placeholders.

Does anyone know of a library to beautify form responsiveness!

Thanks,
Rupesh

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the source code, and it seems like they are using `webcomponents.js`. They are also using a JavaScript framework called `ember.js`.

Take a look at this website

http://webcomponents.org/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was specifically looking for form functionality for responsiveness.